# Socket.IO disconnect event called multiple times when client is offline

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am building a chat app, i use react-native in my client and node js in my server- for the chat app i use Socket.io.

All works great except when i simulate situation when i didn't receive internet connection.

**Way to reproduce:**

1. connect to socket in the server
2. cancel data in my phone
3. disconnect event will call
4. and after every time i get the internet connection again i send init event, because i must after the client disconnected

**Results:**

1. cancel data in my phone, call disconnect event
2. after doing that again- my server called disconnect event twice,
   after close the connection and open it again its called disconnect
       event 3 times and etc...

**Excepted result:**

**cancel data in my phone call disconnect event just once, no matter how much time i will cancel data in my phone and connect again.**

```
import express from "express";
import http from "http";
import ioServer from "socket.io";

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = ioServer(server);

  let users: any = {};
  io.on("connection", (socket: any) => {
    socket.on("init", (userId: string) => {
      console.log("initizalizeeee");
      socket.userId = userId;
      users[userId] = socket;
    });

    socket.on("message", (user) => {
        if(users[user.id])
          io.to(users[user.id].id).emit("message", {
            ...message
          });
        else {
          remoteNotification(message, user.id);
        }
      });
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
      console.log(reason)
      console.log("discoonectttt");
      users[socket.userId] = null;
    });
  });
});

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

After 3 time i get-

```
discoonectttt
ping timeout
5dfbhf42342389fdsc1bbfa
discoonectttt
ping timeout
undefined
discoonectttt
ping timeout
undefined
```

I excepted -

```
    discoonectttt
    ping timeout
    5dfbhf42342389fdsc1bbfa
```

Client

```
export class SocketIo {
  static socket: any = "";

  static socketInit = userId => {
    SocketIo.socket = io.connect(CHAT_SERVER, {secure: true});
    SocketIo.socket.on("message", SocketIo.handleNewMessages);
    SocketIo.socket.emit("init", userId);
  };

  static sendMessage = (user) => {
    SocketIo.socket.emit("message", user);
  };

  static disconnectSocket = () => {
    SocketIo.socket.close();
  };

  static handleNewMessages = async message => {
....
  };
}

* when my app is first setup or back from background i call  SocketIo.socketInit(user.id);
* when my app reconnect after offline mode i call   SocketIo.socketInit(user.id); too


* when my app is closed or in background i call SocketIo.disconnectSocket();
```

"socket.io": "^2.3.0",

Comment: Can you show the socketIO frontend code?

Comment: @i.brod  I updated

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what's going on here to be honest..but it seems to me that maybe you're creating multiple sockets without realizing it. What's the meaning of  SocketIo class? Is it like a wrapper for EACH socket? What purpose does it serve? Also make sure you have exactly the same version of socketio both on the server and in the froentend.

Comment: @i.brod Yes the SocketIo class give me an option to make some process on my client socket from any place in my app, it's very convenience(i saw it's recommended in some places ) and i always open and close when i am create a socket i don't get how can i open multiple sockets .
I use the same version of Socket IO in the server and the client.
Thank you for your response

Comment: Well it's very hard to diagnose the problem this way. Do you know how to use the debugger in nodejs? Try putting "debugger" statements in all relevant places and follow the "flow". Also i assume you can do it in react-native. If you never used the debugger in nodejs, i recommend visual studio code for this..really easy.

Comment: אה חח אני רואה שיש לנו משהו משותף. משעמם בזמן הקורונה,אה?

Comment: Yes, i found the problem you're right, when i added  SocketIo.disconnectSocket(); in the handler that handle when i lost the connection - then it's close the old socket and works fine
Thank You!